# BigEndianUnion is not part of python's ctypes

Tags: python, ctypes

Python documentation says [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#structure-union-alignment-and-byte-order) that " To build structures with non-native byte order, you can use one of the BigEndianStructure, LittleEndianStructure, BigEndianUnion, and LittleEndianUnion base classes"

However:

```
Python 3.6.1 (default, Jul 13 2017, 21:35:51)
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-11)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from ctypes import *
>>> BigEndianStructure
<class 'ctypes._endian.BigEndianStructure'>
>>> BigEndianUnion
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'BigEndianUnion' is not defined
```

Anybody has an idea how to make `BigEndianUnion` available (ideally with python 2.7 too)?

Thanks in advance

[update] p.s. opened https://bugs.python.org/issue33178

Comment: https://bugs.python.org/issue19023 It looks like this never really got implemented in the first place. Perhaps you should create an issue using the link.